# How to logout from a session?

Tags: php

Coz of this virus in China, bosslady asked us to try to do classes online. I want the students to login, so I know who is present.

Login works. It checks user name and password. If correct, I'm in. Logout seems weird!

I have this below for logout.inc.html.php:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="logout">
    <input type="hidden" name="goto" value="/">
    <input type="submit" value="Log out">
  </div>
</form>
```

Shows a nice Log out button when I put this on any page:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/logout.inc.html.php';?>
```

The form above does take me back to the root page when I click the button, so that bit is working. But if I click say, the button for class 19BE1 again, where I should be logged out, I am not asked to login again. It just opens. Maybe some cookie thing??

This is part of /includes/access19BE1.inc.php I got this from my textbook PHP & MySQL: Novice to Ninja

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'logout')
  {
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    unset($_SESSION['password']);
    header('Location: ' . $_POST['goto']);
    exit();
  }
```

It is supposed to unset everything! Will I be timed out eventually?

I got this from stackoverflow, still not logged out!

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'logout')
  {
    //session_start();
    //unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
    //unset($_SESSION['name']);
    //unset($_SESSION['password']);
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    header('Location: ' . $_POST['goto']);
    exit();
  }
```

Any tips please for this virus-avoider??

EDIT： I opened a private window in Firefox. I opened localhost. I get my webpage. I click the button for class 19BE1. I immediately get the login page. I enter a wrong name and number, which brings me back to the login page with the error message. I enter a correct name and password, I get the page I want. So I think login is working.

Maybe, Firefox is saving something??

Comment: How are you checking to see if you are logged in?  I think your problem is there.

Comment: The first time I had to login, name password. After that I saw the page I wanted. So I think it works! (Not an expert!)

Answer (score 0):

If you tired the stackoverflow answer with `session_start()` line commented out, the `session_destroy()` would not work.

You can try the bellow simple code which you can modify to your requirement

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location: index.php');
?>
```